# KeyError: u'xl/worksheets/Sheet1.xml' is given when try to open xlsx file with python xlrd

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

I can not process some files using python xlrd library. 
This is my code,

```
>>> from xlrd import open_workbook, XLRDError
>>> try:
...     book = open_workbook('17112015Rpt1000000178_Report.xlsx')
... except XLRDError as e:
...     print e
...
```

I get the following error.

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 422, in open_workbook
            ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 790, in open_workbook_2007_xml
            zflo = zf.open(component_names[fname])
KeyError: u'xl/worksheets/Sheet1.xml'
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Does your `xlsx` file contain a sheet named `Sheet1`?a issue link https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/150

Comment: yes, it does. I checked the link too, I have the latest verio of xlrd and installed through pip command on Ubuntu

Comment: how your xlsx file generated?Is it generated by third-party programm?

Comment: It was generated from Logrhythm and I have written a java program with apachi poi to covert to the date format  to custom format and save it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Error Message
You may consider upgrade your xlrd Package.

First upgrade your pip (to avoid problems)
Then upgrade xlrd

usage:

```
  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  pip install xlrd -U
```

It worked for me...
Good luck!!